# How can I set multiple progress with queue

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, file-upload, upload

I'm implementing multi uploader with queue in React. This particular queue should have only 5 "slots" for parallel file upload. Rest of the files should wait when free slot will come and then start uploading another one.

**Current implementation**

Here it's just uploading all files one-by-one.

```
private onChange(event: any) {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.setState({
     files: [...files]
   });
   this.upload(files);
}
private doUpload(index: any, files: any) {
  // ... implementation
  xhr.send(formData)
}

private upload(files: any) {
 for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
   this.doUpload(index, files);
 }
}
```

**Goal**

To allow only 5 http requests in parallel. The rest files should wait for free "slot" to start uploading.

Comment: Please show what you've tried for the parallel upload

Comment: Well, I've tried to check all actual progress in `this.state.files`. Something like this:

`for (let index = 0; index < this.state.files.length; index++) {
if (this.state.files.filter((e) => {
return e.progress < 100;
}).length < 3) {
this.doUpload()
}`

Comment: Another time in `this.upload` I was trying to do a recursive approach and delete uploaded already file from the array. Sth like this:

`private upload(files: any) {
for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
      this.doUpload(index, files);
      delete files[index];
      this.upload(files);
    }
}`

Comment: I've also checked in `componentWillUpdate` the progress and the number of the current uploaded files (progress < 100). But react 'explodes' - sth with memory ;)